# Banks providing loans

Tags: banking, trading

Banks are providing loans.

While granting a loan two scenarios can take place

1. The Loan is repaid
2. The Loan is not-repaid

The benefit from a re-payed loan is small profit. (Let's say 5% in general)
The loss from a not re-payed loan is huge loss. (you lost all your investments)

Are there formulas that can calculate the ratio of loss of (based on pseudo-numbers for example) or other theories related to this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an estimate of the probabilities of each scenario, say with probability $p\in[0,1]$ the loan is repaid (assuming no other scenario exists), then you can calculate the expected value of making the loan of size $L$:

- In scenario 1, payoff is $-L+(1+0.05)L=0.05L$ (giving out $L$ and getting back the principal plus interest)
- In scenario 2, payoff is $-L$ (giving out $L$ and getting nothing back)

The expected payoff from making the loan would be 
\begin{equation}
EV=p(0.05)L+(1-p)(-L)=1.05pL-L.
\end{equation}

Comment: But in scenario 2 you are asuming that we are making no loss?

Comment: @jenniferruurs: You're right. I've edited the answer.